# Sorting linked lists one by one in c

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

So, I'm trying to sort my linked list but, there seem to be some problems. So basically my list is this

```
3 6 9 7
5 3 4 6
2 4 1 6
```

and I want to sort the second vertical line. After sorting the second line in ascending order should be like this

```
5 3 4 6
2 4 1 6
3 6 9 7
```

but my code sorts only the second vertical line and doesn't change other lines for some reason like this, how can I fix this?

```
3 3 9 7
5 4 4 6
2 6 1 6
```

And here is my code for sorting

```
void sort(struct node **h)
{
    int i,j,a;

    struct node *temp1;
    struct node *temp2;

    for(temp1=*h;temp1!=NULL;temp1=temp1->next)
      {
        for(temp2=temp1->next;temp2!=NULL;temp2=temp2->next)
          { 
            if(temp2->num1 < temp1->num1)
              {
                a = temp1->num1;
                temp1->num1 = temp2->num1;
                temp2->num1 = a;
              }
           }
       }
}
```

Here is my print function as well

```
void printList(struct node *list) {

   //start from the beginning
   while(list != NULL) {    
      printf(" %d %d %d %d  \n",list->data, list->num1,list->num2, list->num3);
      list = list->next;
   }

}
```

Comment: it is hard to understand how to you hold the different lists. Can you please add the definition of the data types?

Comment: Yes, your code is working with lists, while your printed data is a matrix. Please specify how your data is printed.

Comment: In general the problem is that you are replacing a specific value (num1) and not the lists

Comment: @eyalm Yes, I think so too. But how can I replace the list?

Comment: By vertical line, you mean column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to swap items in a linked list.

- keep the node but replace all the data
- Swap between the pointers themselves

In your solution, you try to swap the data but you changed only one member of the struct. you need to do the same for `data`, `num2`, and `num3`.